# Problems with Dongle K5150 and Iot Core

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

When I connect Dongle K5150 to Raspberry Pi3 and I check interfaces with PowerShell

`netsh mbn show interfaces`

I get this message

`There is no Mobile Broadband interface`

The light of dongle is on and the Sim is online, but it seems that raspberry doesn't see it.

How can is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Did you import the profile with netsh mbn add command?

Comment: Hi @MichaelXu-MSFT, I can't import profile If raspberry Pi3 doesn't see my dongle.
Do you think it could be a problem of power?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What level of power are you supplying the board? It is recommend to use a 5V/2.2A supply.

Comment: I'm using a smartphone power cable.